# Pandas read excel and write to .txt file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I read a excel using pandas to create a txt with all data in one row?

Here an example:

This is an excel File:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | Data1 | DifferentData1 |
| Test2 | Data2 | DifferentData2 |
| Test2 | Data2 | DifferentData2 |

and I want the text file to say this:
Test1;Data1;DifferentData1;Test2;Data2;DifferentData2;Test3;Data3;DifferentData3

This code did not work for me:

```
import pandas

xl_file = pandas.read_excel ("EDDS.xlsx")


print(xl_file)

file1 = open("test.txt","w")
file1.write(str(xl_file))
file1.close()
```

Is this possible?
(and some Boxes of my Excel are 120 Characters long)

Comment: `df.to_csv('file_name.txt', sep=';)` or do you really want all the data on the same line?

Comment: @It_is_Chris  This worked for me, BUT
I would really want to get it in the same line;

Can I do some post Processing?

Can I set the Data to a Variable?

And I would like to remove the 0, 1, 2, 3, at the Front

Comment: You can use the param `line_terminator` and set it to something that is not in your file: `\t`

Comment: @aplayz, I believe you're referring to the index - use `index=False` in the `to_csv` call

Comment: @It_is_Chris  what did you mean with line_terminator?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: @aplayz `df.to_csv('file_name.txt', index=False, line_terminator='\t')` it is a param of [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: @It_is_Chris now it worked;
But one more Problem: there is a tab behind every last item in a line. Can I filter this out? (thx for the help btw)

Comment: @aplayz that was just an example of how to use the param `line_terminator` based on your sample you will want to set it to `;` Try `df.to_csv('file_name.txt', sep=';', index=False, line_terminator=';')`